# htaccess https://example.com/dash/something link redirect problem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have some directories:

```
/
/dash
/something
```

I want to make htaccess to redirect all traffic to it's subfolder index.php , which i did, when i type it works
example.com/dash or example.com/something

But my problem is when i try something like this example.com/dash/login or example.com/dash/another
in this case i'm redirected to / directory

Here is my htaccess in / directory

https:// we.tl/t-NtTDlYKBHr

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!dash/)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dash/(.+)$ /dash/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

And in /dash

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

https:// we.tl/t-lhgQ03tTGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert on this. but I think you achieve it by something like this.
put this file in your parent directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^none/ none/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dash/ dash/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^something/ something/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

also if you put htaccess in every directory you may use this in all directories.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: No its not working :/

http://localhost/dash/rame Redirectes to  /-s index.php again

Comment: Are you using .htaccess in every directory?

Comment: Yes , in every directory

Comment: You need to remove other .htaccess from other directories

Comment: I removed and now localhost/dash redirectes to /-s index.php

Comment: did you keep this line RewriteRule ^none/ none/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
or removed?

Comment: I keep it , now it work but i got new problem with styles, thank you mate i ll fix it with php